# How do I solve my "Core data Illegal attempt to establish a relationship" Problem in Swift?

Tags: swift, database, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**I got the following piece of Code**:

```
let result = try decoder.decode([T].self, from: data)

if let box = Box.item(for: identifier, inContext: context),
    let newTokens = result as? [Token] {

    // Mark all OldTokens that are not inside NewTokens as toBeDeleted
    if let oldTokens = box.token?.allObjects as? [Token] {
        for oldToken in oldTokens {
            if !newTokens.contains(where: { $0.identifier == oldToken.identifier }) {
                oldToken.toBeDelete = true
            }
        }

        // Update / Add all Tokens in newTokens to Database
        for newToken in newTokens {

            var oldToken = oldTokens.filter({ $0.identifier == newToken.identifier }).first

            if oldToken != nil {
                guard let toBeDeleted = oldToken?.toBeDelete else { fatalError() }
                oldToken = newToken
                oldToken?.toBeDelete = toBeDeleted
                oldToken?.box = box
            } else {
                newToken.toBeDelete = false
                newToken.box = box
            }
        }
    }
}

try? context.save()

completion(.success(result))
```

**What the Code should do:**
We got some Tokens from our Server and want to Save them in our CoreData Database. Tokens that are inside the DB but not inside the Backend Result will be marked as toBeDeleted. Tokens that are in Both will be Updated and Tokens that are new will be written into the DB.

**The Problem:**
I got an `"Core data Illegal attempt to establish a relationship"` Error. In my Understanding the Error means, that I try to do CoreData Stuff inside 2 different Contexts.
When I do `newToken.box = box` the error will be triggered. That what I believe at least.

I think i got an diffrent Context with `newTokens = result as? [Token]` and another one with `box.token?.allObjects as? [Token]`.

Sadly I have not an solution for those Problem and need a way to do this one the same context.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried to wrap everthing inside an `Dispatchqueue.main.async` but did not help. Any Ideas ?

Thanks for the Help

Comment: When you create `newTokens`, are the Tokens managed by any context?  I'm guessing, but it's possible the error indicates trying to set a relationship with an object that is not managed.

Comment: @PhillipMills The Token will get an Context when they are decoded as far as i know. We do that for all our server requests. The DB object will be created with decoder.decode([T].self, from: data). But it seems like those context is not the same as for the oldTokens. Thats why i think it crashed

Comment: That's probably correct but to fix it you need to know specifically what context is being used when the Token objects are created.